# Taurus is not taking the Jmeter Setting local path even after changing .bzt-rc file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, taurus

I want to use the existing Jmeter Version (4.0) to run my scripts using Taurus.But Taurus is downloading & taking the latest Jmeter version though i change Jmeter setting Path: in .bzt-rc file.

Updated bzt-rc file to below:

```
# JMeter settings

#modules:
  jmeter:
#    properties:  # JMeter properties for every JMeter run
#    prop_name: prop value
#    system-properties:  # Java system properties
#      sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders: "true"
#    memory-xmx: 4G  # allow JMeter to use up to 4G of memory
    path: C:\Trusted\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\jmeter  # path to local jmeter installation
#    version: 3.2  # version to use
#    plugins:  # plugins to install
#    - jpgc-json=2.2
#    - jmeter-ftp
#    - jpgc-casutg
```

With the Path Provided in Jmeter setting section i expected Taurus to take my local Jmeter copy and run the scripts.But its taking the latest Version of Jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Path should be of JMeter main folder

```
  path: C:\Trusted\apache-jmeter-4.0
```

I'm assuming also you have uncommented `modules:`

Also consider using latest JMeter version, currently 5.1

Comment: Thanks for the inputs.But i am getting below error while using 4.0
12:47:40 ERROR: JMeter STDOUT:
The JMETER_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: @Raghu set `JMETER_HOME` to main directory `C:\Trusted\apache-jmeter-4.0`

Comment: I used Version 5.1 and it works fine now.Thanks for the inputs.