# Taurus - Getting error on running jmx test and yml test

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, blazemeter, taurus

I already have installed JMeter 5.X, I don't know why **bzt** is trying to download it again.
I edited the .bzt-rc file. Provided path of installed JMeter. Below code from **.bzt-rc** file.

```
path: C:\001_team\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin  # path to local jmeter installation ~/.bzt/jmeter-taurus/{version}/bin/jmeter
```

Didn't find a way to set the existing path of installed JMeter.
Tried ti use existing JMETER in cmd:

```
bzt -o modules.jmeter.path=C:\001_Team\apache-jmeter-5.2.1\bin InContact.jmx
```

```js
C:\001_TeamPlatinum>bzt InContact.jmx
13:29:30 INFO: Taurus CLI Tool v1.14.1[0m
13:29:30 INFO: Starting with configs: ['C:\\Users\\teams\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jmx_u679qs83.json'][0m
13:29:30 INFO: Configuring...[0m
13:29:30 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\001_Team\2020-02-21_13-29-30.812601[0m
13:29:30 INFO: Preparing...[0m
[33m13:29:31 WARNING: Failed to check for updates[0m
13:29:31 INFO: Will install JMeter into C:\Users\teams\.bzt\jmeter-taurus\5.2.1[0m
[31m13:29:31 ERROR: Can't fetch https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi[0m
13:29:31 INFO: Downloading: https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.zip[0m
[31m13:29:32 ERROR: Error while downloading https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.zip: Unsuccessful download from https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.zip[0m
100% [                                                         ] ETA:  --:--:--
[31m13:29:32 ERROR: Internal Error: JMeter download failed: No more links to try[0m
13:29:32 INFO: Post-processing...[0m
13:29:32 INFO: Artifacts dir: C:\001_TeamPlatinum\2020-02-21_13-29-30.812601[0m
[33m13:29:32 WARNING: Done performing with code: 1[0m
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57061862/taurus-is-not-taking-the-jmeter-setting-local-path-even-after-changing-bzt-rc-f Here is the way to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `path` setting must point to the root folder of your JMeter installation, not to the "bin" subfolder

So change your configuration to look like:

```
path: C:\001_team\apache-jmeter-5.2.1
```

or
    bzt -o modules.jmeter.path=C:\001_Team\apache-jmeter-5.2.1

and Taurus should pick up your local JMeter installation.

References:

- [JMeter Location & Auto-Installation](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/)
- [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus/)

Comment: Thank you @Dmitri T